# What does "they sing no songs" mean?

Tags: meaning

In the prologue of George R. R. Martin’s book *A Game of Thrones*, Will says:

> My mother told me that dead men **sing no songs**

Does this phrase have other connotations, or does it mean they simply cannot sing because they are not alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When old time knights came back from a quest, they would tell stories and sing songs of their adventure.

The mother is warning her son not to be foolhardy. She is reminding him that not all people who go on an adventure will come back to sing songs about it. Some die and so never come home to sing songs.

Comment: so sing songs refers to them telling their stories of their adventure?

Comment: Yes, it refers to them singing songs of their adventure.